# For Blender+Unity users-- Would Blender's "UV Project Modifier" work in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender, fbx

So, say in Blender you have a Cube that you put a "UV Project Modifier" on, with an Empty (controlled by a Bone) as the Projector. In Blender when you move the Bone, the UV moves on the cube. Great!​

But now let's say you wanted to bring that to Unity. Would that still actually work (being able to move the UV around with bone movement) or would it be busted?

I'm trying to test it myself and it seems a dud but I already struggle with Blender's export process so wanted to check here.

Comment: Rather ask this question here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/